# Android Imageview like HTML Imagemap?

Tags: android, imagemap

If got a big picture with several areas. They should be tap able and then get some info from a listener.
The picture needs also to be zoomable.

I thought something like an imagemap in html would be best way. I found http://catchthecows.com/?p=113 on the web, but i am not sure, if this a correct way. I also ran into some memory problems, since the picture is 1.3 MB on disk and much bigger loaded into the imageview/ram.

Maybe there is a much elegant way to solve this and you can show it to me. Or is the catchthecow the best way?

thx in advance for everybody

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`BitmapRegionDecoder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) along with something like my [`PhotoView`](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library.

I'm afraid I can't give a more detailed answer/implementation at present.